# Rails / Heroku - Updating entries different on local vs heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I am running into an issue with a scaffold where editing or updating an entry to a table leaves it in place on my local server/db however after pushing to heroku updating the database entry pushes the edited post to the bottom of the list. I would like for entries on Heroku to work the same as on my local machine (stay in place after an edit).

I'm assuming this has to do with a difference between sqlite and pg? Just wondering where and how to fix this.

ex.

Local app:

1. entry one
2. entry two
3. entry three

*Change entry two to "entry five"

1. entry one
2. entry five
3. entry three

Heroku:

1. entry one
2. entry two
3. entry three

*Change entry two to "entry five"

1. entry one
2. entry three
3. entry five

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you ordering these records?

Comment: If you're not explicitly ordering your records then you can't expect to get them in any particular order. There is no top or bottom of a table in SQL, you **must** include an ORDER BY clause to get any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I added @posts = Post.order("id DESC") to my controller.